# Getting the number of the buffer inside a window

Tags: vim

I've been using this little remapping pattern to allow me to handle three-way diffs in vim.

```
autocmd VimEnter,TabEnter * if(&diff) |
    \nnoremap do< :exe 'diffget' winnr()-1<CR>:diffupdate<CR> ]c |
    \nnoremap do> :exe 'diffget' winnr()+1<CR>:diffupdate<CR> ]c |
    \nnoremap dp< :exe 'diffput' winnr()-1<CR>:diffupdate<CR> ]c |
    \nnoremap dp> :exe 'diffput' winnr()+1<CR>:diffupdate<CR> ]c |
\endif
```

but now I'm trying to add new tabs that include some two-way diff views of the buffers.  I'm fairly certain the above code only worked because the winnr() happened to be the same as the buffer number associated with the window win simply running vimdiff with three files.  But adding two-way diff tabs, the winnr() no longer lines up with the buffer number, and I haven't been able to find anything in the vim documentation on how to obtain the number of a buffer based on the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't `winbufnr()` what you're looking for?

> winbufnr({nr})
>
> The result is a Number, which is the number of the
>   buffer associated with window {nr}.  {nr} can be the window number
>   or the window ID.
>
> When {nr} is zero, the number of the buffer in the current window is returned.
>
> When window {nr} doesn't exist, -1 is returned.

Comment: I had found `bufwinnr()` but somehow missed `winbufnr()`